# How do you call this assignment? Iterator to pointer?

Tags: c++11

As a hobbie I'm trying this code, which in a loop copy to another string object all the characters except 'a' and 'e':

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string orig_str;
  std::string new_str;
  std::cout << "Please input a string: ";
  getline (std::cin, orig_str);
  for (auto i = orig_str.begin (); i != orig_str.end(); ++i)
      if (*i != 'a' && *i != 'e')
          new_str += *i; // ???

  std::cout << "Original: [" << orig_str << "]\n";
  std::cout << "Changed: [" << new_str << "]\n";
}
```

I have a couple questions:

1. Is this the correct way to do it?

   How do yo call this procedure? Iterator to pointer?

**Update #1**

Using std::copy_if doesn't copy to the new container the allowed letters of the original string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::copy_if;

int main () {
    string org_str; // original string
    string upd_str; // updated string
    upd_str.resize(org_str.size()); // make room
    cout << "Input some string: ";
    getline (cin, org_str);
    cout << "Original string: [" << org_str << "]\n";
    auto it = copy_if (org_str.begin(), org_str.end(), upd_str.begin(), [](int i) { return ((i != 'a') || (i != 'e')); });
    upd_str.resize (std::distance (upd_str.begin(), it)); // shrink to actual size
    cout << "Updated string: [" << upd_str << "]\n"; // show updated string, but is empty
    return 0;
}
```

**Update #2**

Now with working code, I updated it with a vector which allows you to choose which vowels you don't want in the original string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::copy_if;
using std::back_inserter;
using std::vector;
using std::find;

int main () {
    string org_str; // original string
    string upd_str; // updated string
    vector<char> pass = {'a', 'e', 'o'}; // this vowels not allow
    cout << "Input some string: ";
    getline (cin, org_str);
    cout << "Original string: [" << org_str << "]\n";
    copy_if (org_str.begin(), org_str.end(), back_inserter(upd_str), [pass](char i) { auto it = find (pass.begin(), pass.end(), i); return (it == pass.end());});
    cout << "Updated string: [" << upd_str << "]\n"; // show updated string
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This loop uses no pointers, so "iterator to pointer" is probably not a good name for it. This is one way to perform the task. Not "the" correct way. The idiomatic C++ way would be std::copy_if.

Comment: @n.m. using std::copy_if and starting to learn lambas, seems that I'm not using in the correct way because it returns an empty container.

Comment: @Joel: Here's the idiomatic way to do `std::copy_if`: http://ideone.com/O2GxfY

Comment: Thanks @BillLynch, but why the back_inserter?

Comment: @Joel: It allows me to skip the call to `upd_str.resize()`.

Comment: oh...ok...thanks for the input.

Comment: Use std::back_inserter. http://ideone.com/jBevS6 Also pay attention to your copy condition.

Comment: Also your first resize is at a wrong place.

Comment: Added vector, seems working too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is for finding solutions to coding problems.  For advice on improving working code, please use [codereview.se] instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the correct way to do it?

I think **yes**

> How do yo call this procedure? Iterator to pointer?

**No** I rather to call it `dereference an iterator` that is it.

And for putting all lower letters into a string without `a` and `b` I can solve it by `std::regex` library, instead of your for loop, like this:

```
std::regex regex( "[bcdf-z]" );
std::regex_token_iterator< std::string::const_iterator > 
    first(orig_str.begin(), orig_str.end(), regex ), last;
while( first != last ){
new_str += *first; // dereference an iterator
++first;
}
```

**or with `std::remove`**

```
new_str = orig_str;
new_str.erase( std::remove( new_str.begin(), new_str.end(), 'e' ), new_str.end() );
new_str.erase( std::remove( new_str.begin(), new_str.end(), 'a' ), new_str.end() );
```

**or even in one-line with `std::regex_replace`**

```
new_str = std::regex_replace( orig_str, std::regex( "[ae]" ), "" ); // return a copy
```